# regex remove 3 characters before and after /

Tags: javascript, regex, string, character

looking for a simple regular expression for this,

This is the input:

This is a sample text

```
eiwen34EDJ/VUFercsFIR/GRSnrr
```

Output:

```
eiwen34 ercs nrr
```

I want to remove 3 characters before and after '/'. i.e. In terms of my example, `EDJ/VUF` and `FIR/GRS` should be removed.

I was searched for many questions in here but didn't find the solution for it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}/gi
```

This checks for 3 characters before and after the slash and replaces with a space:

```js
var string = 'eiwen34EDJ/VUFercsFIR/GRSnrr';

var newString = string.replace(/[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}/gi, ' ');

console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following regex replacement, where you don't need to put it in case insensitive.

```
/[a-z]{3}\/[a-z]{3}/gi
```